# How can i return the resized image from filereader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, canvas, filereader

I've created a function that takes care of resizing a image, now i want to return the resized image from the function.

I'm working with `react` and know i can fix the problem by using the `state` but i don't like this solution..

Tried returning every different scope, but i still get a `undefined` response. Also when i return the `reader` itself, i get the old data.

*Interface*

```
   interface IHTMLInputEvent extends Event {
        target: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
    }
```

*the resize function*

```
function resizeImage(file: IHTMLInputEvent, width: number) {

        const fileName = file.target.files[0].name;
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsDataURL(file.target.files[0]);

        reader.onload = (event) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = event.target.result.toString();

            img.onload = () => {
                const elem = document.createElement('canvas');
                const scaleFactor = width / img.width;
                elem.width = width;
                elem.height = img.height * scaleFactor;

                const ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, img.height * scaleFactor);

                ctx.canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
                    return new File([blob], fileName, { type: 'image/jpeg', lastModified: Date.now() });
                }, 'image/jpeg', 1);
            };
        };
    }
```

*function for handling the upload(so far)*

```
function handleUpload(e: IHTMLInputEvent) {
        const resizedImage = resizeImage(e, 600);
    }
```

*input field*

```
 <input 
   className={classes.inputForUpload} 
   accept='image/*' 
   type='file' 
   ref={uploadImage} 
   onChange={(e: IHTMLInputEvent) => handleUpload(e)} 
  />
```

I would like to return the new created image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using Promise,

```
function resizeImage(file: IHTMLInputEvent, width: number) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const fileName = file.target.files[0].name;
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = event.target.result.toString();

      img.onload = () => {
        const elem = document.createElement('canvas');
        const scaleFactor = width / img.width;
        elem.width = width;
        elem.height = img.height * scaleFactor;

        const ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, img.height * scaleFactor);

        ctx.canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
          resolve(new File([blob], fileName, {
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            lastModified: Date.now()
          }));
        }, 'image/jpeg', 1);
      };
    };
  });
}
```

With `async`, `await` ,

```
async function handleUpload(e: IHTMLInputEvent) {
  const resizedImage = await resizeImage(e, 600);

  // do you suff here
}
```

JSX,

```
<input 
   className={classes.inputForUpload} 
   accept='image/*' 
   type='file' 
   ref={uploadImage} 
   onChange={async (e: IHTMLInputEvent) => await handleUpload(e)} 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks! i really was breaking my head over this, maybe time for me to dig deeper into async await (i only used this for server responses, etc.) Could you please clarify why this needs to be async await?

Comment: you can use `.then(callback)` an older way of resolving promise. `async` `await` is a syntatical sugar of writing async functionality in a synchronous way.

good to read: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/async-await-javascript-5038668ec6eb

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you don't like the solution of using state?  This seems like a pretty standard use case.

Your state could look something like this:

```
state = {
  imageDescription: '',
  imageUrl: null
};
```

Your action handler would simply setState upon success like so:

```
img.onload = () => {
  ...

  this.setState({ imageDescription: fileName, imageSrc: img.src })
};
```

Finally your render function would look something like this:

```
render() {
  const { imageDescription, imageUrl } = this.state;

  return (
    <Fragment>
       <input 
         className={classes.inputForUpload} 
         accept='image/*' 
         type='file' 
         ref={uploadImage} 
         onChange={(e: IHTMLInputEvent) => handleUpload(e)} 
       />
       <img src={imageUrl} alt={imageDescription} />
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

P.S. you can delete handleUpload and call resizeImage directly.

Comment: Thank you the response! I dont want to use `state` because i would like to keep this component simple and plug and play (to use in multiple places). When using state i need to define the state in every component where i want to use this functionality. I'm using this function to resize the images before sending them to the backend

Comment: You would only need to define state within this one component, not necessarily the parents which import it.  

I see your point for a resizing function though - my experience with file uploads so far has always required re-rendering to either load thumbnails or inform the users of progress.